# Use azure Apim to Call an Api that uses OAuth2 token

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, policies, apim

With Apim i'm trying to call a backend Api that needs a OAuth2 validation. This question are more or less similair to this: [Azure API Management: Oauth2 with backend API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44109671/azure-api-management-oauth2-with-backend-api)
But there are no good answer here...

I have been reading alot about policies and caching.
But can't seem to set it up correctly. I hope to be able to cal the apim, and then the apim calls the backend api to get a token and with that token call an Api to get some output data.
I also found one where i had to setup some policies in the backend-part..
Can anyone help me set up the policies ?

my policy is like:

```
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <set-variable name="originBearer" value="@(context.Request.Headers.GetValueOrDefault("Authorization", "empty_token").Split(' ')[0].ToString())" />
        <send-request ignore-error="true" timeout="20" response-variable-name="bearerToken" mode="new">
            <set-url>{{lookupAccessTokenUrl}}</set-url>
            <set-method>GET</set-method>
            <set-header name="Content-Type" exists-action="override">
                <value>application/x-www-form-urlencoded</value>
            </set-header>
            <set-body>@{
                    return "client_id={{HLR-app-client-id}}&scope={{HLR-scope}}&client_secret={{HLR-secret}}&assertion="+(string)context.Variables["originBearer"]+"&grant_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:client_credentials&requested_token_use=on_behalf_of";
            }</set-body>
        </send-request>
        <set-variable name="requestResponseToken" value="@((String)((IResponse)context.Variables["bearerToken"]).Body.As<JObject>()["access_token"])" />
        <set-header name="Authorization" exists-action="override">
            <value>@("Bearer " + (string)context.Variables["requestResponseToken"])</value>
        </set-header>
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to my own Question :-)
I try to comment on each line, but if you take alle the code and put it together you get a policy to handle Oauth2 in a backend api.

In the inbound section, the cache-lookup-value
Assigns the value in cache to the context variable called “bearerToken”.
On first entry, the cache value will be null and the variable will not be
created.

```
<inbound>
<cache-lookup-value key="cacheAccessToken" variable-name="bearerToken" />
```

Create a variable that contains clientid and secret - needed to call the api

```
    <set-variable name="user-password" value="{{HLR-Clientid}}:{{HLR-Secret}}" 
/>
    <choose>
```

Checks if the context variable collection contains a key called
“bearerToken” and if not found executes the code between the opening and closing
“” XML elements.

```
<when condition="@(!context.Variables.ContainsKey("bearerToken"))">
```

Initiates the request to the OAuth endpoint with a response
timeout of 20 seconds. This will put the response message into the variable
called “oauthResponse”

```
<send-request mode="new" response-variable-name="oauthResponse" timeout="20" ignore-error="false">
<set-url>{{lookupAccessTokenUrl}}</set-url>
<set-method>POST</set-method>
<set-header name="Content-Type" exists-action="override">
<value>application/x-www-form-urlencoded</value>
</set-header>
```

here you define your header Authorization and use the variable that contains clientid and password

```
<set-header name="Authorization" exists-action="override">
<value>@("Basic " +  system.Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes((string)context.Variables["user-password"])))</value>
</set-header>
<set-body>@("grant_type=client_credentials&scope={{HLR-Scope}}")</set-body>
</send-request>
```

Casts the response as a JSON object to allow the retrieval of the “access_token” value using an indexer and assigns it to the context variable “accessToken”.

```
<set-variable name="AccessToken" value="@((string)((IResponse)context.Variables["oauthResponse"]).Body.As<JObject>()["access_token"])" />
```

Store result in cache and where we add the contents of the variable “accessToken” into cache for a period of 3600 seconds.

```
<cache-store-value key="cacheAccessToken" value="@((string)context.Variables["AccessToken"])" duration="3600" />
```

Set the variable in a context-variable, then it can be used right now

```
<set-variable name="bearerToken" value="@((string)context.Variables["AccessToken"])" />
</when>
</choose>
<base />
</inbound>

<backend>
    <!--Creates the request to the backend web service. Here we are placing the response from the web service into the variable called “transferWSResponse”.-->
    <send-request mode="copy" response-variable-name="transferWSResponse" timeout="60" ignore-error="false">
        <set-method>GET</set-method>
        <!--Is the creating the “Authorization” header to be sent with the request.-->
        <set-header name="Authorization" exists-action="override">
            <value>@("Bearer " + (string)context.Variables["bearerToken"])</value>
        </set-header>
        <!--Removes the APIM subscription from being forwarded to the backend web service.-->
        <set-header name="Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key" exists-action="delete" />
        <set-header name="Content-Type" exists-action="override">
            <value>application/json</value>
        </set-header>
    </send-request>
</backend>


<outbound>
    <!--Now we need to return the response message from the backend web service to the caller. This is done in the “<outbound>” policy section. Here we just simply return the value of the variable “transferWSResponse” back to the caller-->
    <return-response response-variable-name="transferWSResponse" />
    <base />
</outbound>
<on-error>
    <base />
</on-error>
</policies>
```